# Highlight deleted posts in Low Quality Posts history, similar to deleted flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

I occasionally review my Low Quality Posts review history, and I like to confirm whether my action was correct/incorrect.

I would like to more easily confirm which posts were deleted. I think an easy addition/change would be to highlight the titles the same as is done in the flagging history. The `deleted-answer` CSS class is even available in the review history page.

I know that the link (`<a>`) tag is removed from the title, but that's not always visually easy to distinguish among tens of lines of titles.

---

### **Current look:**

[image: Low Quality Posts history]

### **Flag history:**

[image: Flag history]

### **Suggested look:**

[image: Low Quality Posts history suggestion]

Comment: You could write a userstyle...

Comment: @JanDvorak But then I'd be the only one to benefit from that...Good idea, though. Thanks!